# Using QVTKOpenGLWidget in Qt Quick 2

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

Is it possible to use `QVTKOpenGLWidget` in a Qt Quick 2 application leveraging QML? I understand that it will be made to work with a `vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow`, but it just isn't clicking in my head so it would be brilliant if someone could post a small example of what is necessary to use `QVTKOpenGLWidget` in QML.

I have searched high and low and while I'm piecing things together as I go, I'm new to VTK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. QVTKOpenGLWidget is intended to be used with the Qt Widgets library, which is different from Qt Quick 2. But you can use it for inspiration for implementing something similar that will work with qml. Luckily for you, others have already done that: [How to render programmatically a vtk item in qml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685872/how-to-render-programmatically-a-vtk-item-in-qml/42024250#42024250)